# C equivalent getevn/setenv in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Is there equivalent for getevn/setenv functions in VB.NET. I have looked at system.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable but it gives the system environment variables like USERNAME, COMPUTERNAME etc. I need to get the variables that are stored in config.user file. Is there any way to do that in VB>NET.
Please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the app.config files?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Save Settings or operate on settings, try Settings Class.

Accessed using My.Settings.Properties.Default. - your settings defined in settings file

Answer (score 0):

You can access configuration data from the `.config` files using the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class.